# In Dice Masters, does an opponent's active character trigger your effects?

Tags: dice-masters

For example, Robin has the card text

> While Batman is active, each of your Robin dice gets...

Does this apply when my opponent fields a Batman die, or only when I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Robin only gets a bonus from your Batman, and would not get a bonus from your opponent's Batman.

From Page 19 of the rules at http://dicemasters.com/wp-content/uploads/mdm/MDM_Rules.pdf

**Powers, Abilities, and Card Text**:
Card text that names a character only considers your characters for its effects. Your card’s 
text doesn’t trigger because your opponent has the same character, nor do your dice get a 
bonus from your opponent’s cards of the same name.

**Active and Fielded**:
When game text says, “While active,” that means “When one or more of this card’s dice are in the field.”

Comment: Thanks!  I had read the rules, but I obviously missed that bit.